# Installing Ubuntu on the SSD of ASUS Vivobook S400CA

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, asus, ssd

I have an ASUS Vivobook S400CA, and I am considering of getting rid of the Windows 8.1 and install Ubuntu 14.04 instead for my studies purposes. I see that I actually have two hard drives on this computer: Disk 0 a ST500LT012-9WS142, and Disk 1 a SanDisk SSD U100 24GB. At the Disk 0 I have several partitions, one of them is OS (C:) and another is DATA (D:), and I have several others which I don't know their purposes, together with one partition for recovery. Disk 1, the SSD, is divided into two partitions.

Would it be beneficial to install the Ubuntu on the SSD (will it give better performance?), and if it is, how should I proceed to doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I've just got an Asus Vivobook S46CA (i7 / 6GB RAM / 20GB SSD / 1TB HDD), with Windows 8 pre-installed by factory.

I've tried a bit to install the Ubuntu 14 as a dual boot with Windows 8. But I was not successful. So I have decided to remove Windows and install Ubuntu 14. Be aware that I'm a beginner in Linux world and my answer might be improved somehow by a more experienced user. But the configuration below has worked up to now.

What I've done with the partitions:

20GB SSD:
. 10GB for /
. 3GB for /var
. 1GB for /tmp
. 6GB for swap
I've based my partitioning on Ubuntu's official installation manual. Please refer to that document.

1TB HDD:
. 200GB for /usr
. 400GB for /home
. 400GB for /DATA (personal media files)

That has worked pretty fine (1 day after). I've formatted all partitions as "primary" and EXT4. It feels that the speed was improved. The boot loader was kept at the 1TB HDD. Everything was done using Ubuntu's 14.10 live session CD, GParted (to remove the old Windows 8 partitions and set the new partitions configuration), and the Ubuntu's installation wizard.

Comment: With 6GB of RAM you will probably never use swap. Better then to just have 2GB on hard drive just to have some. Ubuntu default install is just / (root) and swap. Any instructions for other system partitions are either very old or for specific types of server installs. Better then just to have / on SSD and /home & swap on hard drive. Other partitions for data, backup are then just user choices. I do like to have more than just one very large partition with the newer very large TB sized hard drives.

Answer (score -1):

SSD in Asus s400ca used to cache frequently used blocks on main HDD.
Despite on it, it is not so easy to install Ubuntu due to UEFI on this machine.

So, the easiest way for study purposes is install Ubuntu inside of VirtualBox under Windows.